# RNFSManager undefined after installing react-native-photo-upload

Tags: react-native

After install `npm react-native-photo-upload`, I'm getting the error RNFSManager is undefined.

Does anyone have a similar error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well this package is used by very few people and got like only 175 stars so I recommend you to use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker

in this case, most of the errors are already solved.

Comment: For this package I'm getting the error: NativeModule.ImagePickerManager is null